# Why are pointer to array of char different between rvalues is &"hello" and array of char?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Why are pointer to array of `char` different between rvalues is `&"hello"` and array of `char`?

Why `pointer` to array by `&"hello"` need `const`, but by array of `char` not?

Why `x[0] typeid` name is `char[6]`?

Why `*x = temp2` compile error?

The following observation arose as I was following some question :

```
char temp[] = { 'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
char temp2[] = { 'w','o','r','l','d','\0' };
char (*x)[6] = &temp;
//*x = temp2;//error
x  = &temp2;//OK
cout << typeid(x[0]).name() << endl; 


//char (*y)[6] = &"hello"; //error
char const (*y)[6] = &"hello";//OK
```

output :

```
char [6]
```

Comment: I don't see a single string reference in here anywhere, but just arrays of characters.  Question is confusingly worded (and mostly C, the only C++ is the use of `cout`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*x = temp2` does not work because arrays are not assignable. If you want assignable arrays you should use `::std::array` instead.

`char (*y)[6] = &"hello";` does not work because in C++ string literals are arrays of `const char`.

You declare [`x` as a pointer to array of 6 `chars`](https://cdecl.org/?q=char%20%28*x%29%5B6%5D), so `x[0]` and `*x` (the same thing) denote a reference to an array of 6 chars.

Comment: "Detonate"... ?